# to read the directory location written in file and to create new files in that directory in c++

Tags: c++, debugging, file-io, runtime-error, codeblocks

here is the code for creating the directory it is switch case so i have placed it inside a block.

```
{
int  index = 0 ;

char  path[60];

system ( " cls " ) ;

ofstream  ofile ;

cout < < " \ n Enter path  to  store  bills 

< <( ! Without  spaces  after  symbols  like  slashes  and  colons

< <e.g.  \" c : \\ billing  folder \\ \" : ";

fflush ( stdin ) ;

cin.getline ( path , 60 ) ;

mkdir ( path ) ;

ofile.open ( " Path.dat " , ios :: trunc | ios :: out | ios :: binary ) ;

ofile.write ( path , strlen ( path ) );

ofile.close ( ) ;

goto here1 ;

}
```

and here is the code to create a file in the directory created above,the file name have to be the current date and time for which i have used ctime header.

```
void billingWindow ( )
{
system ( "cls " ) ;

char path [ 60 ] ;

char folder [ 30 ];

struct tm *timeInfo;

time_t now;

time(&now);

timeInfo=localtime(&now);

strftime(folder,30,"%d_%m_%y %H=%M",timeInfo);


folder [ 14 ] = ' \0 ' ;

string foldName ( folder , 14 ) ;

int index = 0 ;

ifstream readFile ( " Path.dat ", ios :: in ) ;

readFile.seekg ( 0 , ios :: end ) ;

int length = readFile.tellg ( ) ;

readFile.seekg ( 0 , ios :: beg ) ;

while ( index <= (length-1) )

 {

  readFile.read ( &path [ index ] , sizeof ( char ) ) ;

  index++ ;
 }

path [ index ] = '\0';

char *newPath = new char [ index ] ; 

strcpy ( newPath , path ) ; //copied into 'newPath' because value of 'path' was showing garbage at it's tail while debugging and watching 

index = 0 ;

strcat ( newPath, foldName.c_str ( ) ) ; //appended newPath with the current date and time stored in 'foldName'

char alpha[ 80 ] ;

strcpy ( alpha ,newPath ) ; //copied in the newPath in alpha because i was not sure of dynamically alloted character pointer's behaviour to create file

delete [ ] newPath;

ofstream writeBill ( alpha , ios :: out ) ;

if ( ! writeBill )
{

    cout < < " Error Occured "< < endl ;
}
```

creation of directory is successful and the code to create directory also created the file containing path properly. whenever i run the debugger in my IDE(codeBlocks) the code works fine but while running the code to test it or running the executable made by IDE program just crash when i select the option to the billingWindow

is there any fatal error in the code,please help me

Comment: There is no error checking of any functions to handle the file. If you add error checking you will probably be identify what is wrong,

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong

```
char *newPath = new char[index];
```

you should have

```
char *newPath = new char[index + foldName.size() + 1];
```

because with C style strings you always have to allocate enough memory to hold all the characters.

Because this is difficult you should always use C++ strings. E.g.

```
std::string newPath = path;
newPath += foldName;
```

which is correct, shorter, easier to write and easier to understand.